# Unable to send email in powershell in body with variables

Tags: email, powershell, send

I am using below script in powershell to send email alerts.I am getting email but I am not getting exact body message from temp variable.

```
$file= get-content sample.txt
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer serverip -f mymailid@domain.com -to mymailid@domain.com -Subject 'Test Msg' -Body "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have PowerShell V3 try it this way:

```
$file = Get-Content sample.txt -raw
Send-MailMessage ... -Body $file
```

On earlier versions try this:

```
$file = Get-Content sample.txt
$OFS = "`n"
Send-MailMessage ... -Body "$file"
$OFS = $null
```

$file will be an array of strings if there is more than one line in the file and you don't use the -Raw parameter of Get-Content.  In this case, putting that variable inside double quotes, causes PowerShell to concat each element of the array using the contents of $OFS as the separator for each element. IF $OFS is not set then PowerShell uses a space.  However you want a newline to preserve the structure on the original file.  Anyway, if you have V3, just use -Raw and all this $OFS stuff doesn't matter.